# UWP App does not create UI elements after deploy

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a problem with an UWP app that I am working on. Basically the app is finished and I want to deploy it outside the Microsoft store.

App working fine when run within visual studio 2017 but when I create app package and install my app, it just open blank page without any ui components. App do not throw any error it do not freez. I can resize my blank window, minimalize, maximize and close. Everything act normal except there is no buttons.

What have I try:

1. I have change my mine page to different one to check if this error occur for one page or in whole app. No mater which page is main it is always empty.
2. I have created new empty page and added simple TextBlock and set it as mine page for app but still it open without this textblock.
3. I try which part of code is running by adding this line of code which will change app background color.

   (Application.Current.Resources["AppColorBackground"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.Crimson;

Application constructor App() runs and change background color.

Page constructor MyPage() runs and change background color.

Page method OnNavigatedTo() runs and change background color.

4. I thought that InitializateComponent() method do not run and do not crate ui componets. After initializateComponent() method I added following line of code

MyTextBox.Text = "New text in block";

To see if MyTextBox exist. App still do not throw error, simply nothing happen.

5. Asked my friends if some have similar problem.
6. Asked google
7. And now I ask you stackoverflow community have you encountered similar problem?

Know I try to start new uwp project in visual studio and rewrite my app step by step and check what line of code will cause the problem.

Some additional info.

I work with Visual Studio community 2017 (ver.15.8.5)

Targeted windows version 1803 build 17134

Min version creators update build 15063

Nuget package that I use: SignalR client, Newtonsoft Json, Telerik UI for UWP

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using NaviParkManager.Controller;
using NaviParkManager.Model;
using NaviParkManager.Pages;

namespace NaviParkManager
{
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

            var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(960, 540);
            ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
            localSettings.Values["launchedWithPrefSize"] = true;
            ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.Auto;
        }

        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            // TitleBar config
            CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
            var titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
            titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
            titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = ((SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["AppColorText"]).Color;

            // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
            // just ensure that the window is active
            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
                rootFrame = new Frame();

                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

                if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
                {
                    //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
                }

                // Place the frame in the current Window
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            }

            if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
            {
                if (rootFrame.Content == null)
                {
                    // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                    // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                    // parameter
                    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(TestPage), e.Arguments);
                    //rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(UserLogInPage), e.Arguments);
                }
                // Ensure the current window is active
                Window.Current.Activate();
            }
        }

        void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
        }

        private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
        {
            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
            //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
            deferral.Complete();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You will definitely need to provide us with some source code, this way we can only guess what is happening. Also, try running the app in release mode in Visual Studio, does the same thing happen then?

Comment: Source code have 567 lines of code and I do not expect that anyone will go through all of that. But I can post code fragments, but which one?
Debuge mode and Relase mode in Visual Studio work ok on two different computers there is no error nothing crash. But after installing application the problem occur also on both computers.

Comment: I think the most crucial parts will be the `App.xaml.cs` file and the first page to be displayed (`MainPage` or similar)

Comment: App.xaml.cs is mostly autogenerated cocde. I try to swap my mine page to different one but it had no effect on the problem.

Comment: Would you be able to create a minimum repo on GitHub which exhibits this behavior? I would try it on my side.

Comment: This will be problematic. I got another app which work as a service and receive data from serial port, work with database and so on. I use signalR to notify my UWP app about change and then use REST to get new data. Without server my UWP app is useless. Creating mockup or cutting this functionality will take some time. Thanks for effort. As I mention I do not expect anyone to go through my entire code. I was looking for a clue where to start digging for a bug. I will create new project and copy code part by part and check when it stop working. Definitely I keep you posted about my findings.

Comment: It definitely is a very weird issue, I am surprised by the different behavior Release vs. packaged

Answer (score 0):

I have found cause of my problem. Following line of code in app.xmal

```
<Style TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppColorBackground}"/>
</Style>
```

It caused weird issue with rendering UI. After deploy whole grid is cover by background color.